# check_auth_continue: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type (Net::SMTPSyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple script that send mails through gmail smtp server in ruby, now I have to move the script to a microsoft exchange server and I keep getting the above error, please I need help thanks,

I have tried the below from irb and it fails with the above error too:

```
Net::SMTP.start('your.smtp.server', 25, 'mail.from.domain','Your Account', 'Your Password', :login)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on google, you have to enable basic authentication to use your script:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/exchangesvradmin/thread/0abab2e0-e8ca-4e07-a095-ca4f55015884

Comment: Sailor JavaMail sends mail through the same channel without having the server admin change anything, I dont have privilege to manipulate the exchange server, and I basically would not have a case to make a request for such since Java Mail sends without issues