# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, smtp-auth

The error that I am getting is:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

Rails.root: c:/Users/Anurag/horneto_123

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Ui6Ofxls8CqtLooHwI4yTF/1ifyP4LCJyNuNv0pQqig=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@admin.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I have tried searching for the solution everywhere, but haven't been able to come across any that could help me resolve this issue on MS windows platform.

I am using MS windows vista as a platform to build a Rails application that can allow users to Sign Up/In. During 'Sign In' is when I get the above error. For development, **I used Ruby 2.1.5 -x64, Rails 4.1.7. SMTP settings are smtp.office365.com, port - 587.** This is a local development on a machine with no real database set up or whatsoever.

The reason for error is unrecognised authentication, but any help in a simplified manner(Step Wise) to get over this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings for smtp(username and pass)
Take a look at 
[check_auth_continue: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type (Net::SMTPSyntaxError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895722/check-auth-continue-504-5-7-4-unrecognized-authentication-type-netsmtpsyntax)

[Net::SMTPAuthenticationError when sending email from Rails app (on staging environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)